# How do you post a value from a form_tag?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

If you have a post action to "do_something/:id" => :start (say with a named route 'start'), how do you create a form_tag that submits the :id based on a select_tag selection by the user ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Assuming you aren't using resources.**

The issue is that you have a post action, however you want to set a GET variable via a form submission(that has to use POST).

You can make the form make a GET request, like so:

```
<%= form_tag(start_path, :method => "get") do %>
<%= select_tag "id", "<option>1</option><option>2</option><option>3</option><option>4</option>" %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: Indeed, i'm just using the route " post 'start/:work_hours' => :start, :as => 'start' ". Isn't this like a standard post action from a form ? It gets a value from an element and posts it to the page, right ? I tried the above and got No route matches {:controller=>"labor", :action=>"start"} :/

Comment: ohhh, i think i see what you mean, putting a /:work_hours after post is like trying to get a value, you are right. Hmm, getting down to changing the route and fixing that.